# R, creating several random numbers from each data frame row

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to generate several random numbers, sampled from normal distribution, for several pairs of mean and standard deviation.
These pairs are stored in a `data frame`, with three columns containing the identifiant of the pair, value of mean and standard deviation as in the following example:

```
ex <- data.frame("id" = c("id_1_0.1", "id_2_0.5"), "mean" = c(1, 2), "sd" = c(0.1, 0.5))
```

To create 10 random numbers for each pair, I used these two lines:

```
tmp <- by(cbind(ex$mean, ex$sd), ex$id, function(x) rnorm(10, mean = x[, 1], sd = x[, 2]))
tmp <- do.call(rbind, lapply(tmp, data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

What I would like to do is to then merge both data frames `ex` and `tmp` to have all the information in one data frame.
With this method, I face a problem of naming due to incrementation so I cannot do a simple merge.

Should I try to solve this using a `regex` formula or is there a simpler solution ?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong variable reference in my answer, had the temporary variable 'a' still in my global environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work for you:

```
library(dplyr)
ex <- data.frame("id" = c("id_1_0.1", "id_2_0.5"), mean = c(1, 2), sd = c(0.1, 0.5))

random_list = apply(ex[,c("id","mean","sd")],1,function(x) {
  data.frame(id=rep(x[1],10),
             random= rnorm(10, mean = as.numeric(x[2]), sd = as.numeric(x[3])))})

ex = do.call(rbind,random_list) %>% left_join(ex)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works perfectly, the trick was to replicate the identifiant in the apply function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use some regex to delete the incrementation counters off your IDs, allowing them to merge with your original IDs. There may be a prettier way to do this, but this appears to work.

```
# Pull rownames in and delete counter
tmp$id <- gsub("(.[^.]*$)", "", rownames(tmp))

# Merge with original data
new <- merge(ex, tmp, by = "id")
head(new)
#         id mean  sd    X..i..
# 1 id_1_0.1    1 0.1 1.1226943
# 2 id_1_0.1    1 0.1 1.0666694
# 3 id_1_0.1    1 0.1 0.8848397
# 4 id_1_0.1    1 0.1 0.9839212
# 5 id_1_0.1    1 0.1 0.9027086
# 6 id_1_0.1    1 0.1 0.9389538
```

Regex: Select a `.` followed by any number of non `.` characters `[^.]*`, starting at the end (`$`)

Comment: It works, thank you for the `regex` code. I validate the other answer because it is more integrated but thank you very much.